# Getting a value from a child struct, and then modifying the child struct: a borrow checker puzzle?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider this toy code:

```
struct X {
    x: usize,
    times_accessed: usize,
}

impl X {
    fn get(&mut self) -> usize {
        self.times_accessed = self.times_accessed + 1;
        self.x
    }
}

struct Y {
    y: usize,
    max_access: usize,
    option_x: Option<X>,
}

impl Y {
    fn get_x(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        match self.option_x {
            Some(ref mut some_x) => {
                let result = some_x.get();

                if some_x.times_accessed == self.max_access {
                    self.option_x = None;
                }

                Some(result)
            }
            None => {
                println!("option_x is not initialized! try calling Y::init_x");
                None
            }
        }
    }

    fn init_x(&mut self, x_val: usize, max_allowed_access: usize) {
        self.max_access = max_allowed_access;
        self.option_x = Some(X {
            x: x_val,
            times_accessed: 0,
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("hello world!");
}
```

I haven't bothered using `Y` in the main function, because the compiler doesn't need me to do that to point out that the borrow checker would not be satisfied with the implementation for `Y::get_x`:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.option_x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:26:21
   |
22 |             Some(ref mut some_x) => {
   |                  -------------- borrow of `self.option_x` occurs here
...
26 |                     self.option_x = None;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.option_x` occurs here
```

I understand the issue from the borrow checker's perspective, and I can come up with a very simple fix: copy the value from `some_x` into `result` (am I not already doing that, after all, result isn't a reference, and `usize` has the `Copy` trait), and then "drop the reference" to `some_x` (would it be using `drop(some_x);`, so I can modify `option_x`? A version of that is presented here, but still doesn't work:

```
fn get_x(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
    match self.option_x {
        Some(ref mut some_x) => {
            let result = some_x.get();

            if some_x.times_accessed == self.max_access {
                drop(some_x);
                self.option_x = None;
            }

            Some(result)
        }
        None => {
            println!("option_x is not initialized! try calling Y::init_x");
            None
        }
    }
}
```

What should one do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you are attempting to replace `self.option_x` while you have a reference to something inside it:

```
Some(ref mut some_x) => {
    let result = some_x.get();

    if some_x.times_accessed == self.max_access {
        self.option_x = None; // <---------
    }

    Some(result)
}
```

Any code after the highlighted point that accesses `some_x` would get an invalid value. This is how programs crash, expose security holes, etc..

In a potential Rust future, a compiler that understands *non-lexical lifetimes* might realize that you don't use that value so the code is ok in the current state. Until then, you can take the entire value out of the `Option` then put it back if your condition isn't met:

```
match self.option_x.take() {
    Some(mut some_x) => {
        let result = some_x.get();

        if some_x.times_accessed != self.max_access {
            self.option_x = Some(some_x);
        }

        Some(result)
    }
```

See also:

- [What disaster does the compiler prevent by disallowing assigning to a borrowed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36225868/155423)
- [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)
- [What are the options to end a mutable borrow in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/155423)